# Why hasn't there been a case of an airliner breaking apart and crashing due to turbulence in the past 40-50 years?

Tags: safety, airliner, turbulence

Most of the breakups involved clear air turbulence as well, the type that still can't be detected today.

Examples like:

- [Boeing 707 (BOAC Flight 911)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOAC_Flight_911) - which crashed near Mt Fuji
- [BAC One-Eleven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1963_BAC_One-Eleven_test_crash) breakup in the 60's
- [Fairchild F-27B](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_Consolidated_Airlines_Flight_55) broke up in turbulence over Alaska
- [Fokker F-28](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NLM_CityHopper_Flight_431) broke up in turbulence after flying into a ''microburst'' in 1981
- [De Havilland Comet](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20140414-crashes-that-changed-plane-design)
  broke up after flying into a storm in the 1950's.

Comment: Mishap investigation reports and engineering lessons learned?

Comment: Agreeing with @MichaelHall, but it would be interesting to know what were these improvements, and from which accidents there were devised.

Comment: @mins Seconded.

Comment: I don't disagree, I guess my point is that the question could be improved per @mins' comment.  Can you cite a turbulence induced inflight breakup?

Comment: @MichaelHall BOAC Flight 911, BAC-1-11 breakup in the 60's, F-27 broke up in turbulence over Alaska, F-28 broke up in turbulence after flying into a ''microburst'' in 1981, De Havilland Comet broke up after flying into a storm in the 1950's. Those are just off of the top of my head.

Comment: So maybe fold that info into your question?

Comment: Not sure if this answers your Q - link to a [BBC article on crashed that reshaped plane design](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20140414-crashes-that-changed-plane-design).

Comment: Flew on Comet in 1964. By then pretty much sorted. As a family flying from Singapore to RAF Lynham we were very aware of the Comet's reputation. As a child, it did'nt really bother me but as we boarded the flight, I can still hear my mother with exclamation "oh my god".

Comment: The BAC One-Eleven that crashed on a test flight on 22 October 1963 did so because the aircraft entered a deep stall, peculiar to rear engine T-tailed aircraft. Not due to CAT.

Answer (score 6):

### Durability of Modern Aircraft

Modern Day airliners (or even those built in the 1970s like DC-10) are built to withstand really high G-Forces. Despite the certification requirements for civil aircraft are +2.5G and -1G.

### Incidents involving high G-Forces

**[Federal Express (FedEx) Flight 705](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Express_Flight_705)**: Highlighted parts of the Incident include, the aircraft (a DC-10) being **steeply pitched up 15°**, then using ailerons to **roll the aircraft to 140° attitude** (way past the certification of maximum 60°).
The aircraft was **flying upside-down, with its engines at full-power, this caused the mach tuck effect** (the airflow over the wings reached the speed of sound).
During Landing, **the aircraft was 16,000kg overweight, really high, really fast**. Captain Sanders made really sharp turns (again exceeding the DC-10's certified limits) and **landed the DC-10 just as it feels in a normal landing**. Despite it being damaged, it was flyable and **is in service with FedEx as of May 2022**

| 1986 | 2015 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 1986] | [image: 2015] |

**[China Airlines Flight 006](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/China_Airlines_Flight_006)**: On  19 February 1985, High altitude upset and **30,000 ft dive** due to spatial disorientation after failure of Engine 4. The failure of Engine 4 lead to asymmetrical thrust and the aircraft began to yaw. This was compensated by the Autopilot using the ailerons. Due to the autopilot using ailerons instead of rudders (The rudder could not be deflected by the Autopilot on that aircraft) to compensate for asymmetrical thrust, the aircraft kept yawing despite completely turning the yoke (100% aileron deflected)

The crew realized the aircraft was banking, the crew was disoriented, they thought the autopilot was not performing corrective actions (rather, not working) and hence disengaged it. As soon as A/P was disengaged, the ailerons no longer compensated the yaw and the **PF neither gave rudder or aileron inputs causing the aircraft to bank instantly leading to an uncontrollable descent**.

When on ground, it was noted that **the landing gear doors broke apart, a lot of the vertical stabilizer was missing from the aircraft, and the G-Forces of about 5G (for 2½ minutes) caused the wings to permanently bend (but not break) but still it landed safely**. Despite such damage, repairs were done and the aircraft was used till late 2014.

| Attitude | Damage Caused |
| --- | --- |
| [image: axes] | [image: damg] |

Such incidents prove that, airliners built today are capable of withstanding high G-Forces without disintegrating mid-air. But windshear (microbursts) is still a concern.

### The LLWAS and Onboard Windshear Alerts

The above incidents prove that aircraft built today (the DC10, MD11, A320/50/80) are highly durable and so explains most of the incidents of mid-air breakup you mentioned. But, they are prone to another problem. Windshear during approach. There have been multiple incidents in the 80s (even in the 90s) where windshear has caused aircraft (even a 737) to smash into the runway (or ground) while landing ([United Airlines Flight 585](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Airlines_Flight_585))

| Downdraft | Windshear |
| --- | --- |
| [image: 0001] | [image: 0002] |

> Source:
> https://safetyfirst.airbus.com/wind-shear-an-invisible-enemy-to-pilots/

But, Modern day airliners have Windshear Detection systems onboard and inform the crew about a potential windshear well before getting into it. The airports are equipped with LLWAS (Low Level Windshear Alert System) whose alerts can be communicated by ATC to the crew.

**This concludes that, due to LLWAS and onboard windshear detectors and also highly durable aircraft makes disintegration due to turbulence a really, really rare scenario.**

| Potential Windshear Alert | Currently in Windshear |
| --- | --- |
| [image: pswsalt] | [image: currws] |

Fun Fact: The De Havilland Comet which you mentioned was so much less durable that, its first version (Comet 1) used to disintegrate due to explosive decompression caused by metal fatigue after a year from manufacture. It had square windows which caused high stresses in the corners due to repeated compression/decompression cycles on each takeoff/landing causing the fuselage to fail. [BOAC (British Airways) Flight 781](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOAC_Flight_781) and [South African Airways Flight 201](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_African_Airways_Flight_201) both crashed in 1954 due to the design and was grounded as it became evident that all Comets were going to explode mid-air. However, De Havilland rectified this issue and launched the Comet 1A (not sure of the model number) but meanwhile the Boeing 707 was launched and airlines preferred Boeing 707 over the Comet. The Comet's last model was Comet 4C which retired in 1997.